# My application doesn't show up in Market on a Honey Nook (and I presume Xoom)

Tags: android, android-manifest, nook

I've got a HoneyComb running nook.  But I can't find my application (Car Cast) in the market... and I don't know why.

I've tried messing with the AndroidManifest's targetSdkVersion="3"  android:maxSdkVersion="4" (and I've tried using 11)

I've also diddled (added/removed) the elements "supports-screens" although it seemed to me just using

```
  targetSdkVersion="3" android:maxSdkVersion="4"
```

Should be all I need to do... my app should just be there...  Why isnt it in the market? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, turns out the application shows up find on the Xoom... something odd about the nook.

Comment: Have you tried to find the app within the market-website? The website will show all your devices with a hint on the devices compatibility.

Comment: Can you post your Manifest.xml file?

Comment: Do not use maxSdkVersion. Instead set minSdkVersion. What is your current minSdkVersion?

Perhaps it is not there because it has no Telephony hardware. 

What permissions, screen sizes and libraries do you use?

Comment: Espiandev is right. Show us your complete AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: NOTE:  This was over a year ago, I dont own a Nook anymore, but the current AndroidManifest.xml is here,

https://github.com/bherrmann7/Car-Cast/blob/master/cc/AndroidManifest.xml